# unable to instal yaml-lint package with gem

Tags: rubygems

I downloaded yaml-lint but when I install it with gem, I'm getting the below error:

```
gem install yaml-lint-master
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'yaml-lint-master' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Whatever package I pass for gem, I'm getting the same error. I'm not sure why I'm unable to use the gem command.

My gem version is 1.3.7

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem is called yaml-lint

```
gem install yaml-lint
```

will do the trick. You don't need to manually download the gem.

Comment: I tried " gem install yaml-lint"  but I am getting the same error.
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'yaml-lint' (>= 0) in any repository